# Camunda Run - How to query database with service task?

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, camunda

I am quite lost with this issue.

I've got to create a project with docker-compose that's supposed to run three different containers.

1. postgresql database container to contain camunda configuration
2. camunda container that can be either camunda run/tomcat/wildfly or spring boot. This container needs to have a "service" that performs some database operation on the camunda db.
3. a spring boot application that deploys a bpmn to the camunda instance. This bpmn has to call the "service" within container nr 2

Here is my problem. I've basically setup everything and most of it seems to work. Deploying bpmns (from container nr 3, the spring boot one), the camunda instance uses the psql db for configuration, etc. However, I am quite stumped about what it means to add a "service" to the camunda container. As far as I know there is no such exact thing as a service. Just service tasks which is probably what is meant in the guide. However, as I am using camunda run (I don't want to create another spring boot application as this would make my intellij project incredibly complicated) I am unsure of how to add this service task of accessing the database. These camunda java delegates do not seem to be an option with the Camunda Run version as this is a prepackaged jar. I am quite lost.

After hours of googling and fooling around does anybody have an idea how to add such a service task/script to Camunda Run? My docker-compose is relatively simple and I'll guess I'll need to mount some kind of file for this task/script.

```
  camunda:
    image: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform
    #     image: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run
    environment:
      - DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
      - DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/camunda
      - DB_USERNAME=camunda
      - DB_PASSWORD=camunda
      - WAIT_FOR=postgres:5432        # waiting for psql instance to be ready
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

The RUN distribution has a lib folder in which you could mount a jar including your Java delegates: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/

An alternative, more like the Camunda 8 architecture, is to use the external worker pattern: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/ext-client/
In this case you don't need to add code to the Camunda runtime.

Here is an example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/c7-external-task-worker
It also uses docker compose to deploy engine and worker together: https://github.com/rob2universe/c7-external-task-worker/blob/main/docker-compose.yml